# How to feed data from a numpy array to train a CNTK regression model

Tags: python-3.x, linear-regression, cntk

I generated some random values inside a 1D numpy array and I'm trying to feed this data into a CNTK model I've created (codes below) to train it. But I'm getting different errors according my approach.

Neural network I've created:

```
mean = 10
stdev = 2 
x = np.random.normal(mean, stdev, 1000)
y = 2 * x + 25

inputs = c.input_variable(1) #Number of variables
labels = c.input_variable(1) #Number of results
layer1 = Dense(1000, activation = c.relu) #input layer with 1000 neurons
layer2 = Dense(1000, activation = c.relu) #hidden layer with 1000 neurons
layer3 = Dense(1, activation = None) #output layer with 1 neuron
model1 = Sequential([layer1, layer2, layer3])
result = model1(inputs)
loss = c.squared_error(result, labels)
learner = c.sgd(model1.parameters, c.learning_parameter_schedule(0.01))
progress_writer = c.logging.ProgressPrinter(0)
```

For approach below (https://cntk.ai/pythondocs/Manual_How_to_feed_data.html) I'm getting this error:

**RuntimeError: The Variable 'Input('Input4', [#], [1])' DataType Float does not match the corresponding Value's DataType Double**

```
progress_writer = c.logging.ProgressPrinter(0)
trainer = loss.train((x,y), parameter_learners = [learner], callbacks=[progress_writer])
```

For this other approach, I'm getting:

**ValueError: non-dict argument (ndarray) is not supported for nodes with more than one input**

```
trainer = c.Trainer(result, loss, [learner])
trainer.train_minibatch((x,y))
```

Could some one give me some help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`trainer.train_minibatch()` only takes a dictionary. So it should be something like this:

```
data = {inputs: x, labels: y}
trainer.train_minibatch(data)
```

Comment: But **inputs** and **x** (as like **labels** and **y**) have different dimensions. In this case, what do you suggest?

Comment: Define your input and labels with the correct shape. 
inputs = c.input_variable(shape=...) #Number of variables
labels = c.input_variable(shape=...) #Number of results

Answer (score 0):

I found it. Thank you for the hints @snowflake, but besides what you pointed, it had another error with numpy shape. It was a vector, however, the cntk work with matrices. So I just reshape it with:

```
x = x.reshape(1000,1)
```

and trained like:

```
trainer.train_minibatch({inputs: x, labels: y})
```